# How to execute some actions in background

Tags: swift, background, urlsession

I make downloading some files from server. After downloading done I am should unzip they and after this I show local push notification for show result. In order not to block UI I added observers for show custom progress line without activity indicator and update this line depends on state.

I want givee user an opportunity make this all in background.

For downloading I create URLSession with bg configuration like this:

```
  private lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MySession")
    config.isDiscretionary = true
    config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()
```

And all work fine for downloading. But my unpacking func still work only in foreground. How I can use it in background?

For unpacking I use lib ZIPFoundation. And code below:

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        downloadService.update(state: .unpacking, for: downloadTask)
        do {
            let documentsDir = try self.fileManager.url(
                for: .documentDirectory,
                in: .userDomainMask,
                appropriateFor: nil,
                create: false
            )
            let newLocation = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent(location.lastPathComponent)
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: newLocation)
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                do {
                    let path = try self.fileManager.url(
                        for: .documentDirectory,
                        in: .userDomainMask,
                        appropriateFor: nil,
                        create: false
                    )
                        .appendingPathComponent("store")
                    try self.fileManager.unzipItem(at: newLocation, to: path, progress: downloadTask.progress)
                    try self.fileManager.removeItem(at: newLocation)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.notificationCenter.add(.languageIsDownloaded)
                        self.downloadService.update(state: .finished, for: downloadTask)
                    }
                } catch {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorHandler.handle(error)
                        self.downloadService.update(state: .failed, for: downloadTask)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            errorHandler.handle(error)
            downloadService.update(state: .failed, for: downloadTask)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing some operation which might consume time and you don't want to kill it then you can extend the time for your operation by executing in UIBackground Task

```
{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier  taskId = 0;
    taskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        taskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

// Execute long process. This process will have 10 mins even if your app goes in background mode.

}
```

The block argument called "handler" is what will happen when the background task expire (10min). Here is a link to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)